# Content Script does not load after Chrome Browser is closed and re-opened in Windows

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working a Google Chrome Extension and when I run it on Windows, I'm noticing that the Content Script does not load after I close the program completely and then re-open it. Only when I manually reload the extension, does the Content Script load on the page. I have iFrames so I need the Content Script set to run at `document_idle`. I am also loading the main extension page into a popup. I have noticed that the content script loads on other pages, but not my main extension page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Google Extension Discussion Group, this is related to a [Chrome bug](http://crbug.com/90161) which lead me to this [solution](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90161#c7):

```
chrome.management.getAll(getAllExtensions);

function getAllExtensions(extensions) {
  for(var i = 0; extension = extensions[i]; i++) {
    if(extension.id != chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@extension_id')){
      chrome.management.setEnabled(extension.id, !extension.enabled);
      chrome.management.setEnabled(extension.id, extension.enabled);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

No more problems after running this.